# Firebase requests never complete on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am currently building a native android app in Kotlin with Android Studio 3 (Canary). I am also utilizing Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Auth. Here are my gradle dependecies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Everything worked fine until communication with my Firebase Database stopped completing. I don't get any errors but all Listeners I have registerd are not being triggerd anymore. For example:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("message")
    ref.setValue("Test", object: DatabaseReference.CompletionListener {
        override fun onComplete(p0: DatabaseError?, p1: DatabaseReference?) {
           println("IT WORKED!")
        }
    })
```

The `println` statement is never reached.

This is some Logger output, which I belive is related. It looks to me like all WebSocket connection attempts time out and are therefore retried. This output repeats over and over again:

```
08-05 15:11:25.899 10820-10909/... D/Connection: conn_12 - Opening a connection
08-05 15:11:55.899 10820-10909/... D/WebSocket: ws_12 - timed out on connect
08-05 15:11:55.899 10820-10909/... D/WebSocket: ws_12 - closed
08-05 15:11:55.899 10820-10909/... D/WebSocket: ws_12 - closing itself
08-05 15:11:55.899 10820-10909/... D/Connection: conn_12 - Realtime connection failed
08-05 15:11:55.899 10820-10909/... D/Connection: conn_12 - closing realtime connection
08-05 15:11:55.899 10820-10909/... D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to OTHER
08-05 15:11:55.899 10820-10909/... D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
08-05 15:11:55.899 10820-10909/... D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 9844ms
08-05 15:12:05.739 10820-10909/... D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
08-05 15:12:05.739 10820-10909/... D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening
connection
08-05 15:12:05.739 10820-10909/... D/Connection: conn_13 - Opening a connection
```

But if I'm right, what is causing this problem? I haven't found any similar issues googling.

I ran the code both on a physical device and in the emulator. I have a web client connected to the same database, which is still working though, so I guess it's not a server-side problem.

The worst thing ist, I reset my project to a point were it used to work but that did not help.

I know this is not much information but I don't know how to further analyse the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. The Firebase client attempts to establish a real-time connection to the Firebase servers using multiple methods. If one of those methods succeeds before the Websocket does, we cancel the Websocket and you see that warning. You can safely ignore the error.

Comment: Uhm... this log output indicates that it's up to try #13. I'm not convinced that is part of the normal handshake/negotiation. It seems more likely that the client simply can't reach the server.